.NET Maui SwipeView is too sensitive - opens when scrolling
SwipeView is great in ListView. I use it for deleting messages, by the user swiping left on a message. However, there seems to be absolutely no sensitivity for the swipe to happen, as it constantly opens whenever I scroll the list of messages. It is almost impossible to swipe perfectly vertically, so any even absolutely slight horizontal movement opens the swipe menu.
This might sound like a small thing, but it completely breaks the experience as almost every scroll opens the swipe menu.
Tested with latest .NET MAUI 8.0 iOS. I used the SwipeView in a bindable stack layout, enclosed in a ListView.
Thank you.
<ListView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
     SeparatorVisibility="None"
     HasUnevenRows="True"
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
     IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
     ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="#ff3b2f" IconImageSource="trash_bin" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.RightItems>
        </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview?view=net-maui-8.0#swipe-threshold Give it a go, tell me if it helps.

no, threshold is only for how far you have to swipe before it triggers. this still keeps showing the SwipeItem underneath.

Does this work correctly when you use CollectionView also why are you using a ListView?

I have tried using both, ListView and CollectionView. The behaviour is the same on both.

There is a similar issue about this problem, you can follow it up here:  SwipeView Threshold changes width and offset of the side menu (when visible).
